# Powering Master-Detail with CloudKit

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I have a `UISearchResultsController` that searches locally while typing, and remotely (CloudKit) when the search button is pressed. The number of results returned needs to be 10-30 (I'm currently testing my app with 25 and it's always enough)

The search results list is populated with `RecordType1`, while it's detail is populated by `RecordType1` and `RecordType2`. My question is how to go about fetching the second reference type while minimizing my requests/sec. I was looking at Apple's [CloudCaptions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/CloudCaptions/Introduction/Intro.html) sample, and they solve the problem by fetching the second record type when each of `RecordType1` is fetched. It seems that this needlessly creates fetch requests (1[`RecordType1`] + 25[`RecordType2`] = 26 requests). How can I reduce this? It seems like it should be possible in two requests (one for `RecordType1` and then one to fetch all the `RecordType2` associated with it).

**UPDATE**: `RecordType2` has a back reference to `RecordType1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I am misunderstanding your problem, I think you can just execute a query on your CloudKit database:

```
    let searchKey = ... // value for recordType1
    let z = CKRecordZone.default()
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "recordType1 == %@", searchKey)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "recordType2", predicate: predicate)
    db.perform(query, inZoneWith: z.zoneID) { (records, error) in
        if error != nil {
            // `records` contains recordType2
        } else {
            // check for errors
        }
    }
```

You can also search for a multiple keys using the `IN` comparison in the predicate:

```
    let searchKeys = ... // [value1, value2, value3, etc.]
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "recordType1 IN %@", searchKeys)
```

### References

1. [CloudKit CKQueryOperation (Apple)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/cloudkit/ckqueryoperation)
2. [CloudKit CKQuery (Apple)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/cloudkit/ckquery)

Comment: So using `IN` I could make an array of `CKReference`s and pass them into the predicate?

Comment: Sorry...not necessarily a `CKReference`, just the key value (of the backlink from `recordType2` to `recordType1`). Whatever the key value is of `recordType1` (quite often, it's a string value, right?)

Comment: Reading through the [`CKReference` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/cloudkit/ckreference) – a `CKReference` is a lower level construct that links records together and helps with some database maintenance functions (e.g. propagating deletes, etc.). This may or may not represent your `recordType1` to `recordType2` relationship. But if you store `recordType1`'s key in 'recordType2', then you can use that in your query predicate.

Comment: I can't seem to find it in the docs, but in a WWDC tips in tricks video, they specifically mention not storing the key, but using `CKReference`

Comment: Ah, thank you for that tip. That's not the only thing they mention in a video that is not in their official documentation. I will have to implement that.

Comment: It's about 30 minutes into this talk https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/231/